# Looping Through Frames of Physics Simulation and Getting Object Info with Blender Python

Tags: python, scripting, physics, rigid-body-simulation

Hey there Blender Community,

I'm trying to figure out the optimal way to use Blender's physics engine to perform simulations and access the information from each frame of the simulation for various other purposes. The idea, ultimately, is to be able to loop through the frames of the animation once the simulation is complete and get information about an object's location, for example, after a rigid body collision.

I was able to successfully accomplish something like this with the following method:

```
def analyze_scene():
    scene = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].frame_end
    object = bpy.data.objects[object]
    frameInfo = []
    for frame in range(1, scene.frame_end):
        scene.frame_current = frame
        bpy.ops.ptcache.bake_all(bake=False)
        frameInfo.append({"name": object.name, "frame": frame,
            "translation": object.matrix_world.translation})

    return frameInfo
```

(Note: There may be an error in this code, but it's just an outline of what I'm doing).

The issue with this is having to call "update all to frame" (bake_all) with every frame. Is there a better way of doing this that isn't so computationally expensive? I've experimented with Scene.update() to no avail.

My thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Can you please confirm how exactly you are using this solution and what Blender version it is for? I am guessing this is for Blender 2.79b? I am hoping I could record the live viewport playback of rigid body physics to keyframes. This would allow me to mouse grab and throw objects around, and hit other objects, recording that in real time with physics running. Very different from an "animated" rigid body object which is NOT affected by gravity. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to call `bpy.ops.ptcache.bake_all()` for every frame, as it runs the simulation **for every frame**.

Just move the call to `bake_all()` above your loop, just after setting `frame_current` to `frame_end` :

```
def analyze_scene():
    scene = bpy.data.scenes['Scene']
    object = bpy.data.objects[object]
    frameInfo = []
    scene.frame_current = scene.frame_end
    bpy.ops.ptcache.bake_all(bake=False)

    for frame in range(1, scene.frame_end):
        scene.frame_current = frame
        frameInfo.append({"name": object.name, "frame": frame,
            "translation": object.matrix_world.translation})

    return frameInfo
```

This should run many times faster, with the code you've given, you were running a simulation of all frames for each frame between 1 and `frame_end`.

**EDIT** : If you just want to iterate through the frames, you don't need to bake anything, just change the current frame with `scene.frame_set(frame)` instead of `scene.frame_current = frame`. As long as you do this with an incrementing `frame`, Blender will compute the keypoints for each frame. For example :

```
def analyze_scene():
    scene = bpy.data.scenes['Scene']
    object = bpy.data.objects[object]
    frameInfo = []

    for frame in range(scene.frame_start,
                       scene.frame_end,
                       scene.frame_step):
        scene.frame_set(frame)
        frameInfo.append({
            "name": object.name, "frame": frame,
            "translation": object.matrix_world.translation
        })

    return frameInfo
```

**NOTE** : You also had written `scene = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].frame_end` in your code, I corrected it with `scene = bpy.data.scenes['Scene']`, I guess that is what you meant.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @pistache! I'll give this a try and let you know the results.

Comment: @ColinConwell : could you tell me if there's a problem with this solution ? or accept it ? (i'm just asking because my low reputation prohibits me from commenting anywhere on this site)

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Your solution does work! Thanks again.

Comment: Can you please confirm how exactly you are using this solution and what Blender version it is for? I am guessing this is for Blender 2.79b? I am hoping I could record the live viewport playback of rigid body physics to keyframes. This would allow me to mouse grab and throw objects around, and hit other objects, recording that in real time with physics running. Very different from an "animated" rigid body object which is NOT affected by gravity. Thanks in advance!